# Fluid SQL Query dependent on variables values

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine, query-builder

I need make query but it's not simple query. 
I need to `setParameters` in the query depending on variables values. Simple code:

```
    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Item::class);

    $query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('b');

    if ($itemId != null) {
        $query->where('b.id = :id')
            ->setParameter('id', $itemId);
    }

    if ($name != "XXX") {
        $query->where('b.name = :name')
            ->setParameter('name', $name);
    }

    $item = $query->getQuery()->getResult();

    return $this->render('default/search/result.html.twig',
        array('item' => $item));
```

But this code is incorrect. Does anybody know how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `$query->andWhere()`

so in your case :

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Item::class);

    $query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('b');

if ($itemId != null) {
    $query->where('b.id = :id')
        ->setParameter('id', $itemId);
}

if ($name != "XXX") {
      $query->andWhere('b.name = :name')
        ->setParameter('name', $name);
}

$item = $query->getQuery()->getResult();

return $this->render('default/search/result.html.twig',
    array('item' => $item));
```

> // NOTE: ->andWhere() can be used directly, without any ->where()
>   before

for more see here : http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html

Comment: Thanks for reply, I will try.

Comment: @Questionamrk let me know, if you still have problem

Comment: problem which I pretend will be complication of IFs bcz I have around 10 variables to check.

Comment: i have updated my answer, you can use "->andWhere() " directly, again if you wish, you can set multiple condition in ->where(), by separating commas, for Ex : `$qb->where('u.firstName = ?1', $qb->expr()->eq('u.surname', '?2'))`

Comment: Ow. So I just had to add 'andWhere' method not just 'where' ?

Comment: Thank you very much, I spent 2 days on this, but I didn't find 'andWhere' method anywhere.